# Processing huge yaml-files via php

Tags: php, yaml

I need to process a huge yaml-file - which is 450 MB - to get the data in a database. Therefore I tried to use "spyc". But the file is too big.

Every chapter has the line `--- !de.db.net,DB::Util::M10lDocument`. And I need the content of every chapter as an array. Therefore I tried to use spyc. But the complete file is too big for that. I don't know how to split for those chapters.

Is it possible to read the complete file just block by block?

Does anyone have an idea how to work with that big file?

Comment: Without an example of the content, it's hard to say. In theory the YAML format should make it reasonably trivial to break things down by going line by line and cutting off at certain events, e.g. a new document or new scalar.

Comment: If the chapters are small enough, you can simply use fgets until you hit the start of a new one, then parse this individual chapter.

Comment: Yes, the chapters are small enough, but I don't know how to parse the chapter as you described. As far as I know spyc just reads a file - and this is too big. I'm open minded for another parser. I would be very thankful if you could write an example of your described solution.

Answer (score 0):

`---` is the [document boundary marker](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#document%20boundary%20marker/) for a YAML stream. Using a YAML parser that processes the file as a stream should allow you to process the file in document sized chunks as long as each document is small enough to fit in available memory.

The [`yaml_parse_file`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php) function provided by the [yaml PECL extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml) includes the ability to parse a single document out of a stream of documents. There is no built in method to iterate over the documents (eg `foreach` support) but you could implement your own loop that fetched sequential documents and halted when `yaml_parse_file` returns `false` indicating that the requested document was not found.

```
<?php
$docNum = 0;
while (false !== ($doc = yaml_parse_file('example.yaml', $docNum))) {
    var_dump($doc);
    $docNum++;
}
```